# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs, ecmascript-5

I am getting this error while running a ReactJs App on the local system. This app is used to build a chrome extension.

Error on terminal

```
../common/src/utils/index.ts 1:23
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:23)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> export const delay = (t: number) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, t));
| 
| export const recurce = (f: Function, timeout: number) => setTimeout(() => f(), timeout);
```

Error on chrome console

```
0.chunk.js:78512 ../common/src/utils/states.ts 4:7
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| const UsaStates = require('usa-states').UsaStates;
| 
> export interface IUSAState {
|   abbreviation: string;
|   name: string;
console.<computed> @ 0.chunk.js:78512
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "extention",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.2",
    "@types/jest": "24.0.7",
    "@types/node": "11.9.5",
    "@types/react": "16.8.5",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.8.2",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "country-json": "^1.0.8",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "react": "^16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.3",
    "react-jss": "^8.6.1",
    "typeface-roboto": "0.0.54",
    "typescript": "3.3.3333",
    "usa-states": "0.0.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "node ./scripts/build-non-split.js",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "web:build": "env-cmd --use-shell 'web-ext build'",
    "preweb:build": "npm run build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chrome": "0.0.86",
    "@types/jwt-decode": "^2.2.1",
    "@types/react-jss": "^8.6.3",
    "env-cmd": "^10.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.5",
    "rewire": "^4.0.1",
    "web-ext": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

NOTE: I found many answers related to this error but all seems related to `babel` but `babel` is not in my package.json

Comment: Babel won't be a dependency as you are using `react-scripts`

Comment: I am not sure what react-scripts OR babel do here. So little detailed help would be appreciated.

Comment: `react-scripts` is a package which contains a whole bunch of common configurations for creating a react app. It includes `babel`.

Comment: See https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/ for more info and troubleshooting tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser is trying to read a *typescript* file, and browsers don't read typescript. It needs to be transpiled to JavaScript. The scripts in your package.json do this for you.

Without seeing what `build-non-split.js` does I'd say try to use the default react-scripts build:

```
node react-scripts build
```

Then enter the project through the resulting `/dist/index.html` file.